# swiftui - save a view to a variable

Tags: swiftui

I have the following:

```
struct Event: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let image: String
}

let events = [
    Event(id: 0, name: "Host Tournament", image: "cup"),
    Event(id: 1, name: "Post Club Info", image: "shield"),
    Event(id: 3, name: "Share A Post", image: "write")
]
```

I want to be able for each Event to hold a separate view.

For example `Event(id: 0, name: "Host Tournament", image: "cup", destinationView: PostView())`

```
let events = [
    Event(id: 0, name: "Host Tournament", image: "cup",destinationView: PostView()),
    Event(id: 1, name: "Post Club Info", image: "shield",destinationView: ClubView()),
    Event(id: 3, name: "Share A Post", image: "write", destinationView: StoryView())
]
```

So i can pass destinationView into my NavigationLink when i loop through events. Im not sure what type the PostView() should be defined as in my struct?

This is what Im currently doing:

```
ForEach(events) { event in
  NavigationLink(destination: //PASS VIEW HERE FROM EVENT) {
     VStack {
         Image(event.image)
          .resizable()
          .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
          .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
          .padding(55)
          Text(event.name)
          .font(.system(.headline))
          .padding(.bottom,20)
         }
         .padding()
         .border(Color.black, width: 4)
         .cornerRadius(10)
       }.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
   }
```

I want to be able to pass in a view depending on the Event its looping through.

Comment: What do you mean by *separate view*? Different types? Would you provide more detail, scratchy example?

Comment: Just updated my question @Asperi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pure design to couple model with view so tightly... but if you want, technically it is possible to do in the following way

```
let events = [
    Event(id: 0, name: "Host Tournament", image: "cup",
         destinationView: AnyView(PostView())),
    Event(id: 1, name: "Post Club Info", image: "shield",
         destinationView: AnyView(ClubView())),
    Event(id: 3, name: "Share A Post", image: "write", 
         destinationView: AnyView(StoryView()))
]
```

Comment: i think you might have misunderstood me, i have put more details in question